# Regex for Date formats

Tags: .net, regex, jquery-validate

Can anyone help me out with regex validation.

I have come up with requirement where my date input can be

```
mm/dd/yyyy
mm/dd/yy
m/d/yyyy
m/d/yy
```

My regex should support all four possibilities.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Yes, it has to check for valid dates.

this is my code and it checks for valid dates after it passes through regex validation.

```
$.validator.addMethod("ValidDate", function(value,element) {
            var result = true;
            if($('#'+element.id).val() != "")
            {  
               var reg = new RegExp("regexcode");
               if (!reg.test($('#'+element.id).val())) 
               {
                result = false;
               }
            }   
            if(result == true)
            {
             $("#"+element.id).datepicker("option", 'mm/dd/yy', $("#"+element.id).val());}
            return result;
            },"Please enter valid date.");
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, have a look at this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Comment: How extensive should the validation be? Does it have to check that it's a valid date, i.e. with correct days per month limit, and leap year consideration?

Comment: Unless you want a *hideously* large regex that deals with all of the leap year rules, etc, it's probably better to do validation by trying to convert to a real date.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: It's not *hideously long.* Just obscene and heinous.

Comment: @Guffa
yes, it has to check for valid dates.

this is my code and it checks for valid dates after it passes through regex validation.

  $.validator.addMethod("ValidDate", function(value,element) {
            var result = true;
            if($('#'+element.id).val() != "")
            {  var reg = new RegExp("regexcode");
               if (!reg.test($('#'+element.id).val())) 
{result = false;}}   
            if(result == true)
            {
$("#"+element.id).datepicker("option", 'mm/dd/yy', $("#"+element.id).val());}
            return result;
            },"Please enter valid date.");

Comment: @shakti: Then you are looking at a huge regular expression. For just one format a regular expression can look for example like this (dd/mm/yyyy format): `^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$`, so bascially four times that... A regular expression isn't really a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/([12]\d{3}|\d\d)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/[0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{1,2}[/][0-9]{1,4}/
```

This keeps the regex simple and easy to modify. You can then validate the values entered for day, month and year individually(for example, whether the year is between 1900 and 2099 etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had need of a regex that correctly matched only valid US-style m/d/y dates. I constructed a regex similar to below, which correctly matched all dates from 1900 to 2099, including all leap years. I did not have need to extract matches, so this regex cannot be used for extracting the numbers from the date.

Be warned that this regular expression is quite heinous and its use may damage your reputation. Also beware of bugs. I reconstructed the below from memory.

```
/^((((0?[13578]|1[02])\/([012]?[1-9]|[12]0|3[01])|(0?[469]|11)\/([012]?[1-9]|[123]0)|0?2\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))\/(19|20)?[0-9]{2})|((0?2\/29\/((19|20)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|1900))))$/
```

I invite others to improve it, as I know it has shortcomings.

I would point out, however, that if you're considering using this regex, you should seriously consider attempting to parse the date instead. Most browsers provide an extension to the Date object which can parse dates and throws an exception when the string does not represent a correct date. It also will handle many more types of date formats than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaskValidator of ajax to validate date ,its very easy to use